# Weighted avgerage of list columns in kdb

Tags: kdb, q-lang

How can I calculate a column of weighted averages from 2 other columns that both have multiple entries per row in kdb?

For example, given the following table:

```
T:([]sym:`a`b`c;size:(2 8;5 2 10;3 7);price:(1 2;1 1 10;2 4))
```

I would like to add the column `(1.8 6.29 3.4)` to the table.

Comment: You have more chances to get better answers if you mention what you have tried, if possible with code.I strongly suggest you to edit the question. Also, reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask could help you to make this a better question; otherwise you risk downvotes and no anser

Comment: Ok I'll take you advice on board Carlos, thanks.

Comment: Hi @CWD I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [each-both](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#each-both) adverb to apply the [wavg](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/stats-aggregates/#wavg-weighted-average) function to each nested list in your table e.g.

```
q)update x:wavg'[size;price] from T
sym size   price  x
--------------------------
a   2 8    1 2    1.8
b   5 2 10 1 1 10 6.294118
c   3 7    2 4    3.4
```